# Install Firefox 41 extension silently

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm making automatic installer for special Firefox extensions. I have read couple of articles about that, but none of the described  methods are not helped.
What I tried to do:

- Placed .xpi file and unpacked unpacked extension directory in %FF_DIR%\browser\extensions
- Placed .xpi file and unpacked unpacked extension directory in %FF_DIR%\extensions
- Placed unpacked extension directory in another directory and added record in registry (`HKLM\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\extensions`, key is extension id and value is full path to unpacked extension)

In all ways unpacked extension directory was:

- Just random name
- ID from install.rdf #1 (`{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}` for example)
- ID from install.rdf #2 (`prism@developer.mozilla.org` for example)

And, as i said, all methods don't give me expectable result. Firefox don't show extensions in list and don't show any notification.
How can i solve it? What actual method using in current version of FF?
Target browser is Firefox 41.0.1, system - Windows 7 x64
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was using for incorrect ID (Both of them were obtained from "targetApplication" sections).
Now I was able to install the plug-in by copying .xpi files to %FF_DIR%\browser\extensions.